# MySql GROUP_CONCAT failing when exporting from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, group-concat

When I test a query using `group_concat` it works fine and outputs the proper comma-delimited list in the row. However, when I then click "Export" at the bottom of the resultset, I get an error saying `#1630 - FUNCTION <databasename>.group_concat does not exist.`

It appears to be treating the reference to `GROUP_CONCAT` as a user defined function. Is there a way to properly qualify the function name so it can find it when exporting? I haven't had problems with exporting before when not attempting to use `group_concat`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(distinct g.name) FROM `users` u
left join usergroupassoc a on u.userid = a.userid
left join usergroups g on a.usergroupid = g.usergroupid
where u.enddate is null and g.enddate is null group by u.userid
```

Comment: It seems to be sensitive to spacing between `group_concat` and the opening parenthesis.  Can you verify you have no spaces there in the actual query you were running?  Source: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247573-distinct/

Comment: That's a possibility--I think phpmyadmin is transforming the query before passing it to MySql. It doesn't appear to be putting a space before the opening parenthesis though, but perhaps it's doing something else MySql doesn't like.

Comment: Have you tried investigating the MySQL general query log to see exactly what query PHPMyAdmin is executing?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll investigate.

Comment: Yep. It is indeed inserting a space before the opening parenthesis. Bugger. It's probably just a bug in this old version of PhpMyAdmin that I'm using and can't change. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

group_concat uses a comma as the default delimiter, which may be preventing phpmyadmin from generating your export file correctly.

Try specifying a semi-colon as the group_concat delimiter:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(distinct g.name SEPARATOR ';') FROM `users` u
left join usergroupassoc a on u.userid = a.userid
left join usergroups g on a.usergroupid = g.usergroupid
where u.enddate is null and g.enddate is null group by u.userid;
```